# Using JQuery with Wordpress the Right Way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been messing around with my custom(not a plugin) jquery slide for Wordpress. I've been searching the whole day for how to integrate javascript in Wordpress but seem to come across many different ways. So my main question is which way is the proper, fastest way to code the script.

From what I read it looks like I should use Wordpress enqueue so that the script is only called on the page it is needed on which in my case is the index.php. But I am not sure of the proper way to do it. Also, should I add something to my functions.php?

Here is the script:

```
<script src="Js/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Js/js/jquery.zaccordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example4 ul").zAccordion({
        slideWidth: 600,
        width: 900,
        height: 250,
        timeout: 5000,
        slideClass: "frame"
    });
  });
</script>
```

And this is what I have now in my header.php:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?> 
<?php wp_head();?>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery.zaccordion.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#slider ul").zAccordion({
        slideWidth: 600,
        width: 800,
        height: 250,
        timeout: 5000,
        slideClass: "frame"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice (and solution):

WordPress Plugin Development - Beginner's Guide
Packtlib press

This is a really good book, very clear, simple, and there are tons of good samples you can use with jQuery.

Moreover you have the real things everybody should do when writing Wordpress plugins ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a plugin then the second best solution is to install the Headspace2 plugin which allow you to add any JS or CSS file to any page from the Wordpress Admin Edit page/post screen.

Also I would turn your inline JS into a external JS file (mycustom.js) and then include it just like you do your other JS files, but that is my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple things I can suggest:

1. Don't include your .js because you're already enqueueing them
2. Register your jquery.zaccordion.js using [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and then enqueue it like you did with jquery
3. You don't need to include `jQuery.noConflict();` since WordPress' jQuery has that declared already.  Only when you include your own jQuery do you need to

Answer (score 0):

You can include jQuery in your theme file and call it the functions.php file. In my case the script was in the js folder (your_theme/js/).

The right way to load scripts in WordPress is to use the function [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

In functions.php in your theme type:

```php
/**
 * Load jQuery script
 */
if (!is_admin()) {
    function register_my_jquery() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/jquery.min.js" );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
    add_action('init', 'register_my_jquery');
}
```